# Stack empty but still see EmptyStackException

Tags: java, stack

I have the below code for matching paranthesis, as you can see my stack is empty by the time it finishes checking for all closing paranthesis, so my expectation is it should never enter while loop. I still receive empty stack exception. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean isParanthesisMatched = findMatchingParanthesis("[({()})]");
    System.out.println("IS BALANCED? " + isParanthesisMatched);
}

public static boolean findMatchingParanthesis(String inputStr) {
    boolean isParanthesisMatched = false;
    Stack<Character> paranthesisStack = new Stack<Character>();
    for(char ch : inputStr.toCharArray()) {
        if(ch == ')' || ch == ']' || ch == '}') {
            paranthesisStack.push(ch);
        }
    }

    while(!paranthesisStack.isEmpty()) { // this should be empty after the last ) so while loop shouldn't execute
        for(char ch : inputStr.toCharArray()) {
            char stackElement = paranthesisStack.pop();
            if(ch == '(' && stackElement == ')') {
                isParanthesisMatched = true;
            } else if(ch == '[' && stackElement == ']') {
                isParanthesisMatched = true;
            } else if(ch == '{' && stackElement == '}') {
                isParanthesisMatched = true;
            } else {
                isParanthesisMatched = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return isParanthesisMatched;
}
```

Comment: Stack trace please. The correct spelling of that word is 'parenthesis'. You should break after setting the variable to `false`.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
 at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)

Comment: The first for loop pushes all closing parenthesis onto the stack. With your sample input you have four elements within the stack when you enter the while loop and the second for loop. The second for loop tries to take one element from the stack for each character in the input, i.e. 8 times. This necessarily fails for the fifth character.

Comment: @ThomasKläger, if you post as a reply, I will accept the answer. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the design of the `findMatchingParanthesis()` method:

The first for loop pushes all closing parenthesis onto the stack. With your sample input you have four elements within the stack when you enter the while loop and the second for loop.

The second for loop tries to take one element from the stack for each character in the input, i.e. 8 times. This necessarily fails for the fifth character.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the input string that you have provided, it will always enter the while loop.

```
paranthesisStack.isEmpty()
```

This will return **False** in this case and the while loop won't be executed. But since you are using,

```
!paranthesisStack.isEmpty()
```

This will return **True** which is why it's entering the while loop.